# textbox in a wpf user control does not work in a Form1(windowsforms)

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

I need a textbox in a user control(Wpf) to output data to form1

```
//sample
  browser.load(tollbar1.url.Text);
```

remembering that, tollbar1 is the WPF user control added manually.

url is our texbox in a wpf user control.

but in this mode, it seems that our client (browser) does not receive the URL text.

Comment: It would be good to have some more details about this somewhat uncommon setup (WPF control on a Winforms form). What is "browser"? Could you verify the value of the Text property in the debugger?

Comment: @Klaus Gütter
in the wpf user control there is a textrbox where it should receive a URL value. Browser are controls created with cefsharp. but I came to replace the browser with label.txt

Comment: So I saw that the label.txt did not receive any value, from the textbox that is in the wpf usercontrol

Comment: *tollbar1 is the wpf user control added manually*: added *manually* to an ElementHost, you mean. -- Add a public method to the WPF UserControl, e.g.,  `public string GetText() => url.Text;`, assuming you have named the TextBox `url`. Then, call the method as `string text = (elementHost1.Child as [The UC Namespace].tollbar1).GetText();`. You could also use a public Property and change the Text with the property setter, if needed.

Comment: how do I change the value of GetText? on a button click for example?

Comment: What do you mean by *change the value of GetText()*? That's a method, it returns a value. If you need to also change the `Text` value of your TextBox, use a public Property instead. Use the getter to return the TextBox `Text` property value and the setter to set a new string. -- You can get/set the Text whenever you need to.

Comment: could you exemplify with a code?please